# How to set a parameterized query in excel based on a cell value

Tags: mysql, excel, powerquery

I have the following query:

```
Select login, Acc_open_time, Acc_Close_time from accounts
```

I've imported the query successfully on Excel
but my problem im trying to set the open time and close time as a dynamic value; this means Cell A1 = open_time and Cell A2 = Close_time 
when I enter the values in Cell A1 and A2

the query becomes like this:

Example:

```
Cell A1 = 2019-07-01 00:00:00
Cell A2 = 2019-07-10 00:00:00
```

```
Select login, Acc_open_time, Acc_Close_time from accounts
Where Acc_open_time='2019-07-01 00:00:00' And  Acc_Close_time = '2019-07-10 00:00:00'
```

I've tried googling it I couldn't find any answer related to parameterized query for MySQL in excel

Any suggestions?

Comment: Excel will see your values entered into A1 and A2 as dates (actual numbers with decimals), but your query shows them as text.   You should be able to format the cell as text and set open = range("A1").value and use that instead of the hard coding.  do the same with close time.

Comment: I've tried it but it didn't work

Comment: How didn't it work and what actually did you try?  Could you post your code?  One big thing is making sure the field in the table matches the value in cells A1 and A2, or it will never work.

Comment: Select login, Set Acc_open_time = Range("A1"),set Acc_Close_time = Range("A1") from accounts

Comment: im sorry if this is not what u meant but this what i understood and im trying

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are looking for. But getting the types of data (field in table and value in cell) will be the important part.
you do need to define the workbook and worksheet that cell A1 and A2 are on.

Since I do not have the connection to your database, I can't change your sql code.
You would need to add the connection and database, tables, etc... to bring back a result and where will you put that result.

```
Sub open_close()
Sub query_table()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim acc_open, acc_close As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' i dislike this, but don't know the name of your workbook
Set wsh = wb.Sheets(1) 'if your cells are on your first sheet in this workbook

acc_open = wsh.Range("A1").Value
acc_close = wsh.Range("A2").Value


Select login, Acc_open_time, Acc_Close_time from accounts
Where Acc_open_time = acc_open And Acc_Close_time = acc_close
End Sub
```

Comment: is this going directly to power query or into vba?

Comment: Like I said, the select statement and where statement are not correct, since you gave no info about where the database for the query is, it's name, etc....

Comment: This is a VBA macro.  You never said you were using power query